# Обозначения лиц женского пола (не профессии)

Tags: определения, род, сложные-слова

Допустимо ли использовать м. р. (если можно, подскажите правило) в следующих предложениях?

*Пасторы навещают женщин — прихожан/прихожанок церкви.*

*Закон... предусматривает обучение специалистов по защите от депортации пострадавших женщин-иммигрантов/иммигранток.*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Допустимо ли использовать м. р. (если можно, подскажите правило) в следующих предложениях?

Можно, но надо разбираться конкретно с каждым случаем. Выручит только стилистическое чутьё, ибо четких инструкций тут нету.

Попробую по порядку. Когда вообще используется мужской род.
Не знаю, как насчет писаного правила, но множественное число, обозначающее группу лиц (куда могут входить лица обоих полов) всегда образовывалось от слова для обозначения мужчин: *москвич, москвичка, москвичи (не москвички), пассажир, пассажирка, пассажиры (не пассажирки), работник, работница, работники.* Женский в этих случаях возможен (но не обязателен) только для групп, где заведомо нет мужчин (спортсменки, учительницы - это только женщины), и для некоторых случаев, где эквивалентного мужского аналога просто нет или участие мужчины крайне редко (няни, доярки, медсестра, роженицы).

Ваш случай попадает под оговорку о полностью женском коллективе. Правда, в том случае, когда речь идет о профессиях, и тут часто предпочтительны "мужские" варианты: *[условия труда] женщин-врачей, женщин-учителей и проч.* Но прихожан/прихожанок очень трудно свести до уровня профессиональной общности.

Итак, ваша идея назвать женщин "прихожанами" в принципе не ошибка, но предпочтителен все-таки вариант "женщин-прихожанок". С учетом необходимой замены дефиса на тире в случае распространенного приложения (прихожанок церкви) имеем:

***Пасторы навещают женщин — прихожанок церкви***

Сложнее с иммигрантками. В принципе-то ситуация похожая, и "женщины-иммигрантки", и "женщины-иммигранты" как минимум не запрещены. Но в силу меньшей распространенности самого термина "иммигрантка" и по историческим причинам (таких женщин чаще называют иммигрантами) варианты представляются равноправными. Однако в юридическом контексте понятия "иммигрантка" специально не вводится, их все равно называют иммигрантами. Поэтому в данном случае я бы предпочел "мужской" вариант.

***Закон... предусматривает обучение специалистов по защите от депортации пострадавших женщин-иммигрантов.***

В данном случае — это до известной степени субъективно, но ничего более предложить не могу.

Answer (score -1):

Гугл вяло отзывается на мужской род и жизнерадостно - на женский.

Правила такого не обнаруживается.

Зато Большой толковый словарь категоричен: он - прихожанин/иммигрант, она - прихожанка/иммигрантка. См. помету "мн. род.; дат.":

[image: введите сюда описание изображения][image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Так как человеку быть-то?  Догадайся мол сама?